# Navbar slide toggle should slide behind navbar, but slides in front

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made this animated navbar, which works as expected.
The only thing that bugs me is the fact that the list of menu items slides open **in front** of the navbar, instead of **behind** the navbar.

I've set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/5ydhgxay/)**

And here's a quick code view (the full code is in the fiddle):

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="#top">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/25/abstract" alt="Logo"/>
            </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" class="lines-button x"> <span class="lines"></span>

        </button>
    </nav>
    <!-- main-nav -->
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.main-nav ul.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
    -o-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped everything but the navigation in the header in a `div`, and gave that `div` the background my menu should've had.

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#top">
                <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
            </a>
        </div>

        <button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" class="lines-button x">
            <span class="lines"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- main-nav -->
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/5ydhgxay/3/

```
$('.lines-button').on('click', function (event) {
        $('.header').toggleClass('absolute');
        $('.main-nav').children('ul').slideToggle(500);
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.main-nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use jQuery for my animations, as mobile performance drastically decreases when using it. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple issue of Z-index I believe. It is a css property which orders the visibility of elements over each other. If you want the nav bar to be in front add

```
.main-nav {
    z-index:1;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because the navbar is part of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Close the header section after the logo div, and add the following CSS :

```
.lines-button {    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbaz/f6m8wz8j/10/)